# C++: Will Not Accept New C-String Input

Tags: c++, c-strings

First off, thanks in advance for your help. This issue is driving me nuts.

I have a program that accepts a c-string, and then can count the number of vowels and consonants. This works without issue. However, I also need to include a function that allows the user to create a new string. The problem is, though, when the user selects "new string" from the menu, it just loops through the `newString()` method, without waiting for the user's input. It then creates a new, blank screen.

Here is the entire program. The `newString()` method is at the end.

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

// function prototype
void printmenu(void);
int vowelCount(char *);
int consCount(char *);
int cons_and_vowelCount(char *);
void newString(char *, const int);

int main() {

    const int LENGTH = 101;
    char input_string[LENGTH];      //user defined string
    char choice;                        //user menu choice
    bool not_done = true;       //loop control flag

    // create the input_string object
    cout << "Enter a string of no more than " << LENGTH-1 << " characters:\n";
    cin.getline(input_string, LENGTH);

    do {
        printmenu();
        cin >> choice;
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
               vowelCount(input_string);
               break;
            case 'b':
            case 'B':
               consCount(input_string);
               break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':
                cons_and_vowelCount(input_string);
                break;
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
               newString(input_string, LENGTH);
               break;
            case 'e':
            case 'E':
               exit(0);
            default:
                cout << endl << "Error: '" << choice << "' is an invalid selection" << endl;
                break;
        } //close switch
    } //close do

while (not_done);
return 0;
} // close main

/* Function printmenu()
 * Input:
 *  none
 * Process:
 *  Prints the menu of query choices
 * Output:
 *  Prints the menu of query choices
 */
void printmenu(void)
{
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "A) Count the number of vowels in the string" << endl;
    cout << "B) Count the number of consonants in the string" << endl;
    cout << "C) Count both the vowels and consonants in the string" << endl;
    cout << "D) Enter another string" << endl;
    cout << "E) Exit the program" << endl;
    cout << endl << "Enter your selection: ";
    return;    
}

int vowelCount(char *str) {
    char vowels[11] = "aeiouAEIOU";
    int vowel_count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(vowels); j++) {
            if (str[i] == vowels[j]) {
                vowel_count++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "String contains " << vowel_count << " vowels" << endl;
    return vowel_count;
} // close vowelCount

int consCount(char *str) {
    char cons[43] = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
    int cons_count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(cons); j++) {
            if (str[i] == cons[j]) {
                cons_count++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "String contains " << cons_count << " consonants" << endl;
    return cons_count;
} // close consCount

int cons_and_vowelCount(char *str) {
    int cons = consCount(str);
    int vowels = vowelCount(str);
    int total = cons + vowels;

    cout << "The string contains a total of " << total << " vowels and "
            "consonants" << endl;
    return total;
}

void newString(char *str, int len) {
    cout << "Enter a string of no more than " << len-1 << " characters:\n";
    cin.getline(str, len);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement `cin >> choice` only consumes the character they type, not the carriage return that follows. Thus, the subsequent `getline()` call reads an empty line. One simple solution is to call `getline()` instead of `cin >> choice` and then use the first character as the choice.

BTW, the `while (not done)` should immediately follow the `do { … }`, and the `return 0` is redundant. Also, you should call newString at the start of the program instead of repeating its contents.

Comment: Another solution is to call `cin.ignore()` after `cin >> choice`, which will drop a byte from the stream.

Comment: @jli: It's less robust, e.g., if the user is silly and types spaces after the characters (or thinks they have to type `A)`). But I'm splitting hairs; yours is a perfectly valid option.

Comment: Yep I agree, just throwing it out there as a possibility. (it would also choke on CRLF making it even less robust)

Comment: @jli: Actually, it would only choke on CRLF if the stream was opened in binary mode on Windows.

Comment: Thank you guys, so much, for the insight. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

`cin >> choice` leaves a newline in the input stream.. which cause the next `getline()`  to consume it and return. There are many ways.. one way is to use `cin.ignore()` right after `cin >> choice`.

Answer (score 0):

The `cin >> choice` only consumes one character from the stream (as already mentioned). You should add

```
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

right after `cin>>choice` to ignore all the characters that come into the stream after reading the choice.

p.s. `#include <limits>`